# how to do couples of word and its number of occurrence using list generator?

Tags: python

trying to print the words and num of occurrence. like that:

in 1.txt:

```
a aba aaa
dd ddd dd
```

my out shold contains:

```
[[a,1],[dd,2],[aba ,1],[ddd,1],[aaa,1]]
```

but it is :

```
 [[a,1],[dd,2],[aba ,1],[dd,2],[ddd,1],[aaa,1]]
```

here is the full code:

```
import re

def get_words_from_string(s):
    return  (re.findall(re.compile('\w+'), s.lower()))


def merge(seq):
    merged = []
    for s in seq:
        for x in s:
            merged.append(x)
    return merged


fp1 =  open('1.txt' , 'r');

set1 = set(line.strip() for line in fp1);

l1 =[]
for x in set1:
    x.split()
    x = get_words_from_string(x)
    l1.append(x)

l1= merge(l1);

out = []
out = [[word , l1.count(word)] for word in l1 if (1 > out.count(word))]
```

the problem is it throws exception if the word is not in out for the first occurrence 
is there a safe way to find if list contains an item in it?

Comment: Please try to figure out why you think it does not work, then revise your question to include your findings.

Comment: What happens when you run this code and what should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And a solution without imports could be:

```
>>> f = open('1.txt', 'r')
>>> words = f.read().split()
>>> word_counter = {}
>>> for word in words:
...    word_counter[word] = word_counter.get(word, 0) + 1
...
>>> word_counter
{'a': 1, 'aba': 1, 'dd': 2, 'aaa': 1, 'ddd': 1}
```

`word_counter` is now a `dict` with the frequences of all the words. If you want it as a list of list, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> word_counter_as_list = [ [k, v] for k, v in word_counter.items() ]
>>> word_counter_as_list
[['a', 1], ['aba', 1], ['dd', 2], ['aaa', 1], ['ddd', 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

with open("1.txt") as f:
   words = f.read().split()

c = Counter(words)

print [[word,count] for word, count in c.iteritems()]
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
out = [[word , l1.count(word)] for word in l1 if (not(-1<l1.index(word)))]
```

says "create a list of word/count lists for each word such that `-1` is not less than the index of the word in `l1`". But `-1` is always less than the index of the word in `l1`, because the index is always positive. So this filters out all the results.

If you remove the `not`, this works as expected. But then the filter is completely pointless. The result of `index` is always greater than `-1`, so nothing is ever filter. That is, unless `word` isn't in `l1` at all, in which case an exception is thrown!

Looking more at your code, you have created a ridiculously overcomplicated program. There's a 3-line program that does what you want. Why are you creating a `set` of lines and then just iterating over them? Why are you using a regex? This is such a simple problem that I'd feel wrong just showing you the best way. But here are some hints:

```
>>> fp1 =  open('1.txt' , 'r');
>>> s = fp1.read()
>>> s
'a aba aaa\ndd ddd dd\n'
>>> s.split()
['a', 'aba', 'aaa', 'dd', 'ddd', 'dd']
>>> set(s.split())
set(['a', 'aba', 'dd', 'aaa', 'ddd'])
```

Comment: yes i uploaded the wrong version of the question, now i fixed it, it should be out.index of course. sorry for that again, i have problems issues with the wifi here. thanks

Comment: @ZoZo123, the new code you posted doesn't work at all. `out` is an empty list while the list comprehension is being run, `index` throws an exception.

Comment: This will iterate over the entire list for every iteration in the list comprehension.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim, I'm confused by your comment. There is no list comprehension here. I intentionally did not present a complete solution.

Comment: Mea Culpa. I read the first line in your answer and made some assumptions that were wrong. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
fp1 =  open('1.txt' , 'r');   
l1 = fp1.read();
    set1 = set(l1.split());
    for it in set1 :
        print it, "count = " , l1.count(it);
```